# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Ïðèçûâíèê',

description varchar(1000) DEFAULT 'Îïèñàíèå ïåðñîíàæà îòñóòñòâ' at line 64

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
id_user int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
pass varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
email varchar(64) NOT NULL,
ip varchar(20) NOT NULL,
last_ip varchar(20) NOT NULL,
last_time int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
ban int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
race int(1) NOT NULL,
gender int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
ava1 varchar(100) NOT NULL,
ava2 varchar(100) NOT NULL,
ava3 varchar(100) NOT NULL,
token varchar(32) NOT NULL,
gold int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '50',
krystal int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
zelen int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
hp int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
exp int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
hp_now int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
power int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
def int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
ability int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
mass int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
skill int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
glory int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
ref int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
battle int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
win int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
loot int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
lost int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
damage int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
pet int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
safe int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
safe2 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
safe3 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
safe4 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
woodoo int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
woodoo2 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
woodoo3 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
woodoo4 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
house int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
cage int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
fence int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
road int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
out int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
plant int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
time_dozor int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '120',
vip int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
last_bat int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
clan int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
clan_stat varchar(64) NOT NULL 'Призывник',
description varchar(1000) DEFAULT 'Описание персонажа отсутствует',
att_description varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Сообщение отсутствует',
bat_timer int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
authlevel int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
helmet int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
necklet int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
weapon int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
shield int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
armor int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
read_msg int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
kosti_g int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
kosti_k int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
kosti_g_stat int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
kosti_k_stat int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
kosti_z_stat int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
kosti_win int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
kosti_lose int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
naper_g int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
naper_k int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
recd_naper_g_stat int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
recd_naper_k_stat int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
recd_naper_z_stat int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
spend_naper_g_stat int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
spend_naper_k_stat int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
spend_naper_z_stat int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
naper_win int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
naper_lose int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mmine int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
msglade int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mbglade int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mpick int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mglass int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mhelmet int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mpicks int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mglasss int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mhelmets int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mflash int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mpow int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mdef int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mabi int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mskil int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mwork int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
mper int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 ;
```

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'N'Ïðèçûâíèê',

`description` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT' at line 64

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,

`ip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
   `last_ip` varchar(20) CHARACT' at line 16

## 1067 - Invalid default value for 'clan_stat'

Comment: It looks like it's having an issue parsing the Russian characters.

Comment: Try putting N before the string. N'characters'

Comment: Also, remove the quotes around the defaults for `int` fields. These are not necessary and could cause problems later on.

Comment: As far as I know, you'll have to specify `CHARACTER SET utf8` in each of your `varchar` columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying a character set:

```
description varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT 'Описание персонажа отсутствует',
```

I'm going off of this example from the MySQL documentaion:

> [11.1.3. String Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html)
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t
> (
>     c1 VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8,
>     c2 TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs
> );
> ```

As far as I know, you'll have to set that for each of your `varchar` columns.

Here's an example SQLFiddle showing this in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4cc6/1

Alternatively, you might just be able to prefix your string with `N`:

```
description varchar(1000) DEFAULT N'Описание персонажа отсутствует'
```

And here's an example of that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6658/1